# PHP Regex : Ignore closing tag of HTML if

Tags: php, html, regex

I can't seem to get this to work and I was hoping for some help.

I'm trying to capture the contents of a specific `div` *(please save the DOM talk, for this specific purpose it doesn't really come into play.)*

**The problem is,** I can't seem to get it to work if there is another `div` with attributes before it on the same line. I tried specifying only match if there's no `>` between `<div` and `class="myClass"`, but I think I'm doing it wrong.

I'm still pretty mystified by regex.

```
/<div(?!>).*?class="myClass".*?>(.*?)<\/div>/mi
```

**(semi) Working example:** http://regex101.com/r/cW0lW6

Comment: Why are you using regex on HTML?

Comment: Technically I'm using it on a PHP string passed via post via ajax for the new version of my CMS. It's for a good cause, I assure you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

`/<div(?=\s)(?:(?!>).)+?class="myClass".*?>(.*?)<\/div>/si`

Comment: Cool. Care to elaborate on `(?:(?!>).)+?` ? Why the `.` anychar and `+?`

Comment: Its a fancy way to write a class level `[^>]+` but what a class won't do is `(?:(?!some junk string).)+`. Niether the `?` is necessary, nor is `[^>]` entirely correct, but thats for another day that requires a 15 page regex. All the `.*?`'s are not correct either, thought I would just start out with some basics.

Comment: All sorts of whooey in these regexes. Many questions, like closing tag amongst `[^>]*`, its endless, but doable. Most just want a quick and dirty solution, they don't realize the hidden gotcha's.

Comment: True. Those endless 'if and but' issue is why I rarely use it, but it does come in very handy for parsing small strings. I'm sure in time it will all make sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> **You can't parse [X]HTML with regex.** Because HTML can't be parsed by
>   regex. Regex is not a tool that can be used to correctly parse HTML.

See: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

I suggest using [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) for parsing XML and HTML in PHP.  It's basically much the same syntax as jQuery, only it's on the server side.

Comment: For my purpose, this particular solution is probably the *only* way. Using the DOM in this case would be, imo, very hacky. 99.9% of the time I agree this may cause issues. This use would be the .1% , thus my request to spare me on the topic.

Comment: @kcdwayne I disagree: you **should never use regex to parse HTML**. Simply use [DOMDocument](http://de2.php.net/domdocument). It's really easy, when you understand it - *learning by doing*.

Comment: I *do* understand the DOM, and can traverse it just fine. The point is, all I'm doing is discarding a bogey container that I used to safeguard an important string of PHP. I'm doing it this way to reduce security risks within the new version of my CMS, that way I can eliminate any malicious PHP that might be inserted while protecting my own. You only saw a snippet outlining the problem. I didn't want a lecture, I wanted a solution to a *regex* problem. And the 1st answer of the linked question is clever, I've seen it several times.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this (simple way):

```
~<div[^>]+?class="myClass"[^>]*>(.*?)</div>~si
```

or this (more efficient way if you have a lot of attributes):

```
~<div(?>[^>c]++|\Bc|c(?!lass=))+class="myClass"[^>]*+>(.*?)</div>~si
```

Note that these patterns don't work if your div tag contains another div tag.